# Unexpected result when removing substring from a string

Tags: python, substring, python-2.x, strip

I have a string `s`, and I want to remove `'.mainlog'` from it. I tried:

```
>>> s = 'ntm_MonMar26_16_59_41_2018.mainlog'
>>> s.strip('.mainlog')
'tm_MonMar26_16_59_41_2018'
```

Why did the `n` get removed from `'ntm...'`?

Similarly, I had another issue:

```
>>> s = 'MonMar26_16_59_41_2018_rerun.mainlog'
>>> s.strip('.mainlog')
'MonMar26_16_59_41_2018_reru'
```

Why does python insist on removing `n`'s from my strings? How I can properly remove `.mainlog` from my strings?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Dang, I thought I looked for dups. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs for [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) you will see that:

> The chars argument is a string specifying the **set of characters** to be removed.

So all the characters in `'.mainlog'` (`['.', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'l', 'o', 'g']`) are stripped just from the beginning and end.

---

What you want is [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to replace all occurrences of `'.mainlog'` with nothing:

```
s.replace('.mainlog', '')
#'ntm_MonMar26_16_59_41_2018'
```

Answer (score 2):

From Python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Currently, it tries to strip all the characters which you mentioned ('.', 'm', 'a', 'i'...)

You can use string.replace instead.

```
s.replace('.mainlog', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function. `strip` removes characters from the beginning and end of the string. By default spaces, but you can give a list of characters to remove.

You should use instead:

```
s.replace('.mainlog', '')
```

Or:

```
import os.path
os.path.splitext(s)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to the strip function, in this case, `.mainlog` is not a string, it's a set of individual characters.

That's removing all leading and trailing characters that are in that list.

We'd get the same result if we passed in the argument  `aiglmno.`.